# How to capture form input with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've read a few stackoverflow answers to this question and the answers I've seen either require the use of another module (react form) or seem hacky and over complicated.

The goal of the code below is to simply capture the input of the form as `e.target.value` and log the information to the console. The problem is `e.target.value` returns undefined and I do not know why, nor do I know the recommended way to capture form input using react-redux. I want to know the recommended way to do this without the use of a third party module.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';



class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: ""
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({
            data: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>

            <form onSubmit={this.props.togglePlayAction}>
            <input type="text" value = {this.state.data} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
}




const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        togglePlayAction:(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log(e.target);        // form is output
            console.log(e.target.value); // undefined

        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

Comment: You are not using redux state here... why do you connect redux store to your component if you do not dispatch any actions to it?

Comment: That looks right to me. Where are you logging e.target.value?

Comment: Why not just adding a `handleSubmit` on your Form and calling `togglePlayAction` from there? That way you'll be certain that you have the correct event reference

Comment: `e` is the form, so it does not have a `value` property. The `value` is on the input element and also in the components state.

Comment: also the `mapDispatchToProps` should be the second argument to the `connect`. The first is for the `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: See https://codesandbox.io/s/w6nz4v24q5

Comment: Thanks @ Gabriele Petrioli .   This example is helpful

Comment: `e.target.value` isn't undefined for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/2pvnppkv4j. Maybe your question needs clarifying.

Comment: @jacob, the OP is talking about the dispatched `togglePlayAction` (*defined at the bottom*) which is triggered on submit.